# Dump an array in an acf field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a list of selections in which people chose an option. Those choices are added to an array `$players`. I use Advanced Custom Field in Wordpress and I don't know which type of field chose. Like in fact, it has to be empty before people save this page.

```php
<div class="team_players">
<?php
for ($i = 1;$i < 6;$i++)
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sp_player',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($query->have_posts()):
?>
                    <label for="players">Joueur <?=$i ?></label>
                    <?php
        echo '<select name="players[]">';
        echo '<option value="default">Choisissez un joueur</option>';
        while ($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();
            echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</select>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If just want to save the array data and reuse it later to visualize, you can use `json_encode($array)` to encode an array and save it as plain text. Later, you can use `json_decode($str)` to get the value back and use it.